# Why do I keep getting Notice: Array to string conversion?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a mysql database but every time I get the Notice: Array to string conversion. I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone kindly help?

My form

```
<div class="panel-body">

<form role="form" method="post" action="client_post.php" class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Hospital No:
</label>

<div class="col-sm-5">
<input required  class="form-control" name="Hospital_no" placeholder="Patients' Hospital Number">
     </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date of New Status</label>
```

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">New Status</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <select required name ="art_status" class="form-control">
                                <option></option>
                                <option value = "ART Restart" name="ART Restart">ART Restart</option>
                                <option value = "ART Transfer Out" name="ART Transfer Out" >ART Transfer Out</option>
                                <option value = "Pre ART Transfer Out" name="Pre ART Transfer Out">Pre ART Transfer Out</option>
                                <option value = "Lost to Followup" name="Lost to Followup">Lost to Followup</option>
                                <option value = "Stopped Treatment" name="Stopped Treatment">Stopped Treatment</option>
                                <option value = "Known Death" name="Known Death">Known Death</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-5">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update" name="submit" >

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

I'm trying to make the update from this page (client.php)

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{


$Hosp_no = ['Hospital_no'];
$art_status = ['art_status'];
$art_date = ['art_start_date'];

$update_client = "UPDATE `pat_reg` SET  `art_status` = '$art_status', `art_start_date` = '$art_date'  WHERE `Hospital_no` = '$Hosp_no'";


if (mysqli_query($dbcon,$update_client))
{
    echo"<script>alert('Record Updated')</script>";
    //echo"<script>window.open('client_update.php','_self')</script>";
}


$dbcon->close();

}
```

Please help.

Comment: `$Hosp_no = ['Hospital_no'];` should be `$Hosp_no = $_POST['Hospital_no'];` and this code is wide open to SQL injections.

Comment: @John Conde what do I do to avoid SQL injection. I'm scared of getting hacked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `$_POST` superglobal allows you to access the values submitted in the form.

Change the following:

```
$Hosp_no = ['Hospital_no'];
$art_status = ['art_status'];
$art_date = ['art_start_date'];
```

to this:

```
$Hosp_no = $_POST['Hospital_no'];
$art_status = $_POST['art_status'];
$art_date = $_POST['art_start_date'];
```

---

PS. You should be escaping the user's input before querying the database (or, ideally, use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7P8kz1yT-k)) or you may find yourself being hacked very quickly if released to the public.